# Perl Regex quantification Error precced

Tags: regex, perl, grep

When I use quantification in precced, return this error, see multiple examples:

```
printf 'Joe Satriani\nWhitney Houston\n' | grep -Poi '(?<=J\w)[\w\s]+'
e Satriani

printf 'Joe Satriani\nWhitney Houston\n' | grep -Poi '(?<=J\w+)[\w\s]+' 
grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length

printf 'Joe Satriani\nWhitney Houston\n' | grep -Poi '(?<=J\w{2})[\w\s]+' 
Satriani
```

I can't use quantification in precced?

Comment: @Cylian, That's not true. `(?<=a{2})` works fine.

Comment: @ikegami: My apologies, but I really mean to say ``Perl does not support **infinite** repetition inside lookbehind``, like ``(?<\w+);``!

Comment: @Cylian, True, though that's an incomplete account of what's not supported. e.g. `(?<=a|bc)`.

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, all the strings that can be matched by a lookbehind must be of the same length. Apparently, it's the same with your `grep` tool.

In Perl, your problem would be solved using captures.

```
say $1 if /J\w+\s+(\w[\w\s]*)/;
```

In Perl, `\K` often comes in useful to address similar problem when doing a substitution, and it look it's supported by `grep` too!

```
$ printf 'Joe Satriani\nWhitney Houston\n' | grep -Poi 'J\w+\s+\K\w[\w\s]*'
Satriani
```

I'm impressed!

Comment: GNU grep with -P links against libpcre, which tracks common Perl features: [\K was added to pcre before Perl 5.10 stable was even released](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-commit/2007-07/msg00978.html).